# Scrollview not scrolling to the child-views completely

Tags: android, scrollview

So I' added a bunch of EditTexts programatically to a ScrollView (the quantity depends on users' input) and I'm trying to check if the user left one empty, set an error and focus the particular edittext. The problem is that when I try to scroll to that specific edittext, it doesn´t scroll enough, so some of those won't event reach the visible part of the scrollview.

**I want the EditText to be in the uppest visible part of the ScrollView so that the keyboard won't hide it.**

Any ideas?

Here is that part of the method:

```
public void StartNextActivity(View view) {
    String et = null;
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {                    //x is users' input
        et = editTexts.get(i).getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(et)){
            editTexts.get(i).setError("Please insert an Id")
            ScrollView sView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView3);
            sView.fullScroll(editTexts.get(i).getTop());
            return;
        }else {
            ids.add(et);
        }
    }
    Intent next_intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
    startActivity(next_intent);
}
```

And this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".FirstActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Please insert something"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/scrollView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
    android:layout_width="379dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:onClick="StartCarRentActivity"
    android:text="Continue"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3" />
```

Comment: Is it OK if you change `android:windowSoftInputMode` value to `adjustResize` in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I already tried this, but it doesn't seem to work, the ScrollView still scrolls when the keyboard appears, losing the focus of the editText

Comment: Why don't you try NestedScrollView.

Comment: I will, but I almost got it figured for the ScrollView. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
sView.smoothScrollTo((int)editTexts.getX(),(int)editTexts.getY());
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, was really helpful, now the scrollview scrolls to the specific edittext I want. The remain problem is to open the keyboard, it's like the action would reset the scrollview position.

Answer (score 0):

try using a `view` below `scrollview`  and set its visibility to invisible

```
<view
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relDisplayName"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Comment: I added the view like you suggested below the `scrollview`, but now it won't compile the app.